# Can't go into BIOS to change boot device

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, bios, multi-boot, grub2

I completely erased my Hard Drive and installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Lenovo B570 laptop. 
After a few months of using it I wanted to remove it, so I reboot my computer and pressed F12 (MultiBoot List.) 
GRUB2 came up instead of the Boot Device selection list, so I tried to get into the BIOS, but GRUB came up again and I could not change my Boot Device. 
I tried looking up how to remove GRUB, but all the guides I found said I had to boot from my Windows 7 Installation Media, which was not possible. I tried DEL, ESC, F2, F12, Backspace, FN + F2, FN + F12, SHIFT + F2, and everything I could think of, and I even spammed the buttons in the same second after I hit the power button. Nothing works.

Any Idea how to stop this?

Comment: its very weird that grub comes up instead of bios setup. I would assume that means that you did not manage to tell it to enter the bios in time. are you sure you are hitting the right key at post?

Comment: -1 see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick google search and it [looks](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/BIOS-Access-B570-i5-Sandybridge/td-p/418891) like the default key for BIOS access if F2, not F12. If you tried that one, like Frank said, you're probably just not hitting it in time. Try spamming the bios key while turning the machine on if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Bios key may be different for different systems.For some PCs it is f2 for some f1 and for some others it is delete.

Comment: @gladiator2345 Yes, I know, but it seems like its F2 for his particular laptop.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friend had the same issue.At last the issue turned out to be with the keyboard of his laptop. If you are using PC, try connecting another keyboard. If using laptop, take it to the service center.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with windows 7 or ubuntu or multi-boot or grub. You're simply not managing to get into the BIOS. In your case, when you don't manage to get into the BIOS, the next thing is grub but that is not very relevant. If you took the hard drives out completely and tried to get into the BIOS then Grub wouldn't come up. All that nonsense about windows 7 and ubuntu and grub and multiboot is all irrelevant. And you didn't even mention trying keys other than F12 like F2 or DEL.

Answer (score -1):

This is because Windows was previously in hibernate state, next time when it reboots it remebers that state and bypass all BIOS key (this is a stupid design!). So you never get a chance to get into BIOS settings, no matter what keys you click!

The solution is simple: let the stupid BIOS forgets the stupid hibrtate state, by 
1. removing the computer battery first
2. clicking and holding on the Power button for 1 minute

Then install the battery back and restart, F2 and F12 will work.

Ps: I spent 1 hour on firguring this out and it indeeds worked for my Lenovo laptop.

Comment: Hello! If I read the question right, he/she doesn't have Windows installed any more (they removed it and installed Ubuntu), and he clearly says he's "rebooting my computer" (not putting it in hibernation).

Answer (score -1):

I litterally just had the same issue and came to the same conclusion as you did Rock.

Except in my case I didn't even have to remove the battery 4 bios reset. Once I turned it off for a minute, the bios allowed me to push the F2 key again for reentry.

Comment: You might have had the same problem as Rock, but it is not the same as what's in the question.